# Mime is this a virus?

Tags: malware

I run analisis with clam Tk and this file is always tagged as a threat...

/usr/share/mime/mime.cache

Should I remove it from terminal or what should I do with it?

Comment: If this is the only anti-virus program you are running then please also install a 2nd one and compare the results. If both complain about the same file it might be interesting to investigate it. All anti-virus programs have a HIGH false positive rate but those false positives tend to be different between different anti-virus. Besides that: the notice is probably due to the cache file being updated between 2 scanning sessions.

Comment: Sounds familiar: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=mime.cache+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE\_2012\_0110 FOUND](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611291/pua-win-exploit-cve-2012-0110-found)

Answer (score 2):

`mime.cache` is part of [MIME database](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html#idm140625828626720) (also mentioned on [gnome developer](https://developer.gnome.org/shared-mime-info-spec/#idm140625828626720) page ), which is used to determine filetypes. It's not a virus.

Comment: Thanks Serg... But when I run an analisis with clam TK it appears as a threat to be removed... Should I remove it or just ignore the threat