# Permanently logged out because CalmTK told of a malware to delete

Tags: filesystem, security, malware, antivirus, clamav

After doing a full recursive scan of the File System, it potentially recognized 13 threats, one of which was `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache` file.

After putting it in quarantine, and restarting the machine, I am not able to login into my administrator account.

Using the guest account to seek help.

Can't restore what's on other accounts neither can't access any files to undo. How can this be resolved.

I would prefer if the system can be made to generate a new cache file, would not prefer to restore a potential infected system data.*( But if there's no other way, so be it)*

Please help.

EDIT

This looks to be a serious problem with ClamTk based system security. This post - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2295431 - helped in resolving this issue.

In guest account access console(ctrl+alt+f1), login to admin and type `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

Comment: Antivirus, including clamtk, is notorious for false positives. You need to read the messages and do your footwork. Probably the easiest thing to do is re-install as we really do not know what you deleted. Your other option is to identify what files you deleted and then search what package contains the file and reinstall the package(s). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/611291/clamav-pua-win-exploit-cve-2012-0110-found-usr-share-mime-mime-cache

Comment: Yeah. I am finding it the hard way. ;)

Comment: The terminology in Linux is a bit different then windows. In Linux we use HIDS such as tripwire or OSSEC. I like OSSEC but it is overkill for most desktop users. NIDS I use snort + base but again overkill for most desktop users. 99.99 % of your security concerns are solved with 1. Strong passwords, 2. Do not run programs from outside the ubuntu repositories, 3. Do not run as root, and 4. apparmor. If you are very paranoid, use Fedora or RHEL with selinux and confined users. Run unknown or insecure apps in a selinux sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

> one of which was `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache` file.

When I see that the 1st thing I would think: false positive. That file is owned by "root" so how do you expect a virus to edit this file if it does not have your admin password?

1st advice: learn about Linux security. It will prevent you from making mistakes. Remember to keep your admin password safe. For instance: don't input it when asked when you know it should not be asked. When you install software you can be asked. When you use sudo it will be asked every 15 minutes. When you get asked when your browser opens ... don't input it. =Think first=

> After putting it in quarantine, and restarting the machine, I am not able to login into my administrator account.

I would not let you in either **;-)** *What you did here is far worse than any virus would be able to do.*

> Can't restore what's on another accounts neither can't access any files to undo. How can this be resolved.

- From a tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>):

  sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime

  This will not  restore any mime types added after your installation.
- Or boot from a live session and restore the file (I assume you know where it was moved to?). If you do not know how to do this you could also reinstall without formatting.

2nd advice:

Please ditch ClamTK (anti virus on linux just does not work: the amount of false positives is so high it is utterly useless) and learn the basics: use a good admin password and keep is to yourself, don't download random software, don't install software you do not tend to use, stick to USC and maybe PPA's from launchpad, use online mail (like gmail), reguraly check your outgoing connections (from your router) and there is no need for anti-virus software.

For a bit more advanced user: create a partition outside of / and /home and store your personal files there. Create a backup routine for this partition. That way you can always format / and /home and mount your user partition. When there is a problem restore a backup.

This makes it far more easier to fix problems.

Comment: About monitoring outgoing connections, can you elaborate further on the steps? Good idea about the isolated partition option. I would definitely do that.

Comment: After doing some research, executing `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` did the work from the console. I would update the question.

Comment: Cool! editted it in. That makes it far less of a problem :)

Comment: outgoing connections: all router are capable of logging. Might need to turn it on though. Problem: all routers manufacturers do it differently so you might want to open it (through your browser) and check around the options ;)

Comment: What do you mean by `This will not restore any mime types added after your installation`

Comment: Exactly what it says.  You restore to a default. That default does not meant the exact same contents as the file you used. Restore the file in quarantine to get that back.

Comment: Although I agree with your post I would caution 1. Most people say "virus" when they may mean malware and 2. Programs gain root access via bug that allow "arbitrary code" to be run. See https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ and bug reports such as https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1648806 . "Arbitrary code" means the would be cracker can run any code or program such as bash, and once they have shell access they can escalate privileges via several techniques and some "Arbitrary code" will run as root, especially if the bugs are in programs that run as root such as the kernel or kernel modules.

Comment: I make a distinction between virus and malware. When someone says virus I assume virus ;-) And regarding the 2nd: feel free to try and hack my system. I have a honeypot waiting for you :)

Comment: @Rinzwind - I know you make a distinction between virus and malware, I was pointing out to you that when you assume when someone says virus they mean virus - I do not think that is a safe assumption. I have no interest in hacking your system or honeypot and I think hacking and security are a bit beyond these forums. Beware of "Arbitrary code" and bugs that allow access to memory, they are the gateways and can do a lot of damage even without root access.